# minecraft bot как обойти античит

Tags: minecraft

Я пишу анти афк бота для маинкрафт с помощью mineflayer.
Проблема в том, что его кикает античит каждые 5 часов.
Я сделал бота более медленным и похожим на игрока, время "жизни" увеличилось, но его по прежнему кикает.
Предложите идеи, как можно обойти анти-чит ?

Comment: Вы уверены что проблема именно в поведении? На месте администрации, я бы ограничил максимальную длину сессии каким-то достаточно большим временем, с которым не столкнутся 95% игроков и 5 часов вполне подходит под такой лимит.

Comment: Да, я подумал об этом и сделал чтобы бот ложился спать рандомное время и не играл больше 8ч в день